# Как не включать в группировку case when?

Tags: postgresql

Есть небольшой sql запрос, который должен выдавать значение по полям, но запрашивает группировку, если включаю в группировку то я получаю не те данные, которые хотел бы видеть , запрос выглядит вот так:

```
CREATE TABLE client_calls (client_number VARCHAR(255), dt DATE, title VARCHAR(255),count VARCHAR(255));
```

```
INSERT INTO client_calls (client_number, dt , title,count )
VALUES
('89874234523', '2021-10-10', 'Как оцениваете сервис?', '4'),
('89874234523', '2021-10-10', 'Как оцениваете работу мастера?', '5'),
('89874234524', '2021-10-11', 'Как оцениваете сервис?', '3'),
('89874234524', '2021-10-11', 'Как оцениваете работу мастера?', '2'),
('89874234525', '2021-10-12', 'Как оцениваете сервис?', '5'),
('89874234525', '2021-10-12', 'Как оцениваете работу мастера?', '3'),
```

```
select
      (case when title = 'Как оцениваете сервис?' then count
      else
      0
      end) as hello,
      (case when title = 'Как оцениваете работу мастера?' then count
      else
      0
      end) as znach,
      sum(case when title = 'Как оцениваете работу мастера?' then count
      when title = 'Как оцениваете сервис?' then count
      else
      0
      end) as all,
      client_number as client,
      dt as date1
from client_calls
group by client_number, d
```

То есть код запрашивает добавить в группировку title и count , подскажите пожалуйста, как можно обойти group by или же сделать что-то иначе?
Cейчас пишет ошибку "column "title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate"
. Если добавить title и count в group by будет выдавать примерно такой результат:
[image: Результат с group by]
Нужно сделать такой:
[image: Нужный результат]

Comment: @Akina, я сформулировал, под кодом написан вопрос

Comment: @Akina исправил

Comment: @Akina подскажите что можно сделать в select'е?

Comment: Не, а как соотносятся исходные данные и показанный результат? куда делись сведения по клиентам 89874234524 и 89874234525, почему они проигнорированы?

Comment: @Akina я привел пример с 1 номером, у других будет аналогичная ситуация

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT client_number,
       dt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN title = 'Как оцениваете сервис?'
                THEN "count" :: INT
                ELSE 0
                END) AS hello,
       SUM(CASE WHEN title = 'Как оцениваете работу мастера?'
                THEN "count" :: INT
                ELSE 0
                END) AS znach,
       SUM(CASE WHEN title IN ('Как оцениваете сервис?',
                               'Как оцениваете работу мастера?')
                THEN "count" :: INT
                ELSE 0
                END) AS "all"
FROM client_calls
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e9a608f36b87f39699242cbb31dc1544

Кстати, хранить число в текстовом поле (я про `count VARCHAR(255)`) как бы неправильно... И использовать служебные слова как имена полей - тоже.

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, он будет суммировать все поля с похожим title

Comment: @МихаилДужарь *он будет суммировать все поля с похожим title* Вот этой фразы не понял от слова "совсем". Что значит "похоже"? Оператор `=` не умеет "похоже", он требует точного совпадения. Запрос выполняется. Логика запроса соответствует задаче (вернее, тому огрызку, который тут размещён как решаемая задача). результат соответствует показанному эталонному. Что ещё нужно? Есть вариации, когда запрос даст результат, отличающийся от ожидаемого? такие исходные данные - в студию. Иначе это возражения ни о чём.

Comment: он будет суммировать поля с одинаковым title , к примеру у нескольким клиентам задали вопрос "Как оцениваете сервис?" они ответили по разному, оператор SUM будет суммировать все значения count если будет такой title , группировка тут только сгруппирует столбцы с номерами телефонов и датой

Comment: @МихаилДужарь Исходные данные, на которых такое наблюдается, и требуемый результат - в студию. Вернее, либо SQL-кодом в текст вопроса, либо ссылкой на соотв. fiddle. *оператор SUM будет суммировать все значения count если будет такой title* Посмотрите более внимательно на выходной набор и выражение группировки. А если одному и тому же клиенту за день вопрос задали три раза - так это кто накосячил?